# Convert Latitude and Longitude to point in 3D space

Tags: python, math, 3d, latitude-longitude, data-conversion

I need to convert latitude and longitude values to a point in the 3-dimensional space. I've been trying this for about 2 hours now, but I do not get the correct results.

The **Equirectangular** coordinates come from [openflights.org](http://openflights.org/data.html). I've tried several combinations of *cos* and *sin*, but the result did never look like our little beloved earth.

---

In the following, you can see the result of applying the conversion [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) suggests. I think one can guess from context what `c4d.Vector` is.

```
def llarToWorld(latit, longit, altid, rad):
    x = math.sin(longit) * math.cos(latit)
    z = math.sin(longit) * math.sin(latit)
    y = math.cos(longit)
    v = c4d.Vector(x, y, z)
    v = v * altid + v * rad
    return v
```

[image]

*Red: X, Green: Y, Blue: Z*

One can indeed identify North- and South America, especially the land around the Gulf of Mexico. However, it looks somewhat squished and kind of in the wrong place..

---

As the result looks somewhat rotated, I think, I tried swapping latitude and longitude. But that result is somewhat awkward.

```
def llarToWorld(latit, longit, altid, rad):
    temp = latit
    latit = longit
    longit = temp
    x = math.sin(longit) * math.cos(latit)
    z = math.sin(longit) * math.sin(latit)
    y = math.cos(longit)
    v = c4d.Vector(x, y, z)
    v = v * altid + v * rad
    return v
```

[image]

---

This is what the result looks like without converting the values.

```
def llarToWorld(latit, longit, altid, rad):
    return c4d.Vector(math.degrees(latit), math.degrees(longit), altid)
```

[image]

---

**Question**: How can I convert the longitude and latitude correctly?

---

### Solution

Thanks to TreyA, I found [this](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html) page on mathworks.com. The code that does it's work is the following:

```
def llarToWorld(lat, lon, alt, rad):
    # see: http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html
    f  = 0                              # flattening
    ls = atan((1 - f)**2 * tan(lat))    # lambda

    x = rad * cos(ls) * cos(lon) + alt * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
    y = rad * cos(ls) * sin(lon) + alt * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
    z = rad * sin(ls) + alt * sin(lat)

    return c4d.Vector(x, y, z)
```

Actually, I switched `y` and `z` because the earth was rotated then, however, it works! That's the result:

[image]

Comment: `altid` is the altitude, but what is `rad`? Is that the radius of earth? Are `altid` and `rad` in the same units (feet)? What if you only use the radius (i.e. just `v = v * rad`)?

Comment: also look at googling 'lla to ecef' - latitude/longitude/altitude to earth-centered earth-fixed.

Comment: @TreyA Perfect, thank you! Found this: http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html It is the correct formula. :) You can make your comment an answer if you want the rep, and this way I can also mark my question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *TreyA* statet, `LLA to ECEF` is the solution. See http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html

Answer (score 18):

I've reformatted the code that was previously mentioned here, but more importantly you have left out some of the equations mentioned in the link provided by **Niklas R**

```
def LLHtoECEF(lat, lon, alt):
    # see http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html

    rad = np.float64(6378137.0)        # Radius of the Earth (in meters)
    f = np.float64(1.0/298.257223563)  # Flattening factor WGS84 Model
    cosLat = np.cos(lat)
    sinLat = np.sin(lat)
    FF     = (1.0-f)**2
    C      = 1/np.sqrt(cosLat**2 + FF * sinLat**2)
    S      = C * FF

    x = (rad * C + alt)*cosLat * np.cos(lon)
    y = (rad * C + alt)*cosLat * np.sin(lon)
    z = (rad * S + alt)*sinLat

    return (x, y, z)
```

Comparison output: finding ECEF for Los Angeles, CA (34.0522, -118.40806, 0 elevation)
My code: 
X = -2516715.36114 meters or **-2516.715 km** 
Y = -4653003.08089 meters or **-4653.003 km** 
Z = 3551245.35929 meters or **3551.245 km**

Your Code: 
X = -2514072.72181 meters or **-2514.072 km**
Y = -4648117.26458 meters or **-4648.117 km**
Z = 3571424.90261 meters or **3571.424 km**

Although in your earth rotation environment your function will produce *right geographic region* for display, it will **NOT** give the right ECEF equivalent coordinates. As you can see some of the parameters vary by as much as **20 KM** which is rather a large error.

Flattening factor, `f` depends on the model you assume for your conversion. Typical, model is [**WGS 84**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System); however, there are other models.

Personally, I like to use [**this link**](http://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/coord/llhxyz.htm) to Naval Postgraduate School for sanity checks on my conversions.

Comment: This works but you first need to convert angles to radians. And lat/long values are usually supplied as degrees.

Comment: As @TomislavMuic indicated you have to converted *degree* lat lon to radians before using above snippet. To do that just use math.radians() function.

Answer (score 15):

you're not doing what wikipedia suggests.  read it again carefully.

they say:

```
x = r cos(phi) sin(theta)
y = r sin(phi) sin(theta)
z = r cos(theta)
```

and then:

```
theta == latitude
phi == longitude
```

and, in your case, r = radius + altitude

so you should be using:

```
r = radius + altitude
x = r cos(long) sin(lat)
y = r sin(long) sin(lat)
z = r cos(lat)
```

note that the final entry is `cos(lat)` (you are using longitude).

Comment: Unfortunately that is the same result as pixture #2 shows.. :(

Comment: no it's not.  lat/long are swapped only for z.  you swapped them all.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly the same, but equals very much the second picture. And it's very much equal to the first picture when swapping lat and long. The link I found by searching ``lla to ecef`` (Thanks to TreyA) is perfect. See: http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/aeroblks/llatoecefposition.html

Comment: it should be ```x = r cos(long) cos(lat)
y = r sin(long) cos(lat)
z = r sin(lat)```. Note how lat is the angle from the xy-plane not from the z-axis as wikipedia suggests.